# PHP | how to get a path to a file without including folders outside of the root of my project

Tags: php, path, directory

I am trying to load a CSS file in a custom block for my Concrete5 site, but am having issues. The import for my css looks like this:

```
$layout_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
<link href="<?php echo $layout_dir; ?>form.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
```

Which will trying to import my styles with this url:

```
http://pragmatic.dev/Users/brady/Code/pragmatic/public/packages/theme_caboodle/blocks/hero_block/form.css
```

This issue is I need the path to exclude the:

```
/Users/brady/Code/pragmatic/public
```

part of my path, so the base of the path is the root of my project like this:

```
/packages/theme_caboodle/blocks/hero_block/form.css
```

How can I setup my import to only include the path from the root of the project like this?

```
/packages/theme_caboodle/blocks/hero_block/form.css
```

I also need this path to not break when put on a server or anyone else's local machine. So another user using this block my have a different folder structure because they downloaded it off a market place, so I need to keep that in mind.

This is my solution so far, but its pretty gross I find:

```
$baseDir =  getcwd() . '/';
$fullDir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
//use this path for importing
$blockDir = str_replace("$baseDir","",$fullDir);
```

Comment: $layout_after = explode("/public", $layout_dir)[1] . "/";

Comment: Your solution is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for the part of the path starting with '/packages', the following regexp will do:

```
$layout_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';
preg_match('%/packages/.+%', $layout_dir, $matches);
```

Then $matches[0] contains what you are looking for.

Comment: This solution worked best for me!! I just added the server to the path as well  to spice it up a little bit, using this:

$row['assetPath'] = '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $pathMatches[0];

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways but a simple way :

```
<?php

$layout_dir = "http://pragmatic.dev/Users/brady/Code/pragmatic/public/packages/theme_caboodle/blocks/hero_block";

echo removeFromUrl($layout_dir, "/public", 1); // 0 = Left of /public, 1 = Right of /public

function removeFromUrl($mDir, $mStringToSplit, $mNumber){
    return explode($mStringToSplit, $mDir)[$mNumber] . "/";
}
```

Result :

[image]